# View still depends on column even after I have removed the explicit (as well as transitive) dependencies?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

Assume I have the following table and view:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (a int, b text, c text);
CREATE VIEW my_view AS SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE b = 'foo';
```

The table has some data:

```
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (1, 'foo', 'first');
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (2, 'foo', 'second');
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (3, 'foo', 'third');
```

I realise that column `b` *always* has the same value `'foo'`. I decide that the entire column is unnecessary, and wish to drop it.

Because I like to be explicit about my dependencies, to make sure I don't accidentally drop more than I should, I avoid using the `CASCADE` keyword, opting instead to redefine the dependent view manually:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW my_view AS SELECT * FROM my_table;
```

The view now no longer has any explicit dependency on column `b`, so the column should be safe to delete.

```
ALTER TABLE my_table DROP COLUMN b;
```

However, as I try to drop column `b`, I get the following error message

```
ERROR:  cannot drop table my_table column b because other objects depend on it
DETAIL:  view my_view depends on table my_table column b
HINT:  Use DROP ... CASCADE to drop the dependent objects too.
```

Why does this error message appear even after removing the dependency on the column to be dropped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR: The view definition statement is only evaluated once, not each time the view is queried.**

It appears that I have misunderstood how [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) statements like `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW` are evaluated.

I had assumed that the definition of the view (or at least, its `SELECT` clause) was reevaluated verbatim upon querying the view. From that point of view, the expanded form of

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW my_view AS SELECT * FROM my_table;
```

would be

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW my_view AS SELECT a, b, c FROM my_table;
```

before the column `b` was dropped, but

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW my_view AS SELECT a, c FROM my_table;
```

after column `b` was dropped.

However, after my attempt to drop column `b` failed, I decided to inspect the interpreted definition of `my_view`.

```
postgres=# \d+ my_view
                 View "public.my_view"
 Column |  Type   | Modifiers | Storage  | Description 
--------+---------+-----------+----------+-------------
 a      | integer |           | plain    | 
 b      | text    |           | extended | 
 c      | text    |           | extended | 
View definition:
 SELECT my_table.a,
    my_table.b,
    my_table.c
   FROM my_table;
```

As it turns out, it seems the view definition is evaluated only once, and that the `*` wildcard from the `SELECT` clause was expanded to column list `a, b, c` upon evaluation. It seems this `*` wildcard is *not* re-evaluated as the underlying table has changed, contrary to my initial beliefs.

I assume this means I must redefine the view *after* the table's column list has changed.